# Frameset / Frames not working in Rhomobile

Tags: frames, rhomobile

Trying to implement frames wherein clicking on a link in left frame should open in right frame.
Here is the code i am trying:

app/test/main.erb

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
<frameset rows="26%,74%">
  <frame src="/public/images/header.png" name="topy" scrolling='no'>
<frameset cols="30%,70%">
  <frame src="left" scrolling='no'>
  <frame name="right" src="right" scrolling='no'>
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

app/test/left.erb

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
   <A href="http://google.co.in" target="right" >Search Engine</A>
   <A href="slide3.html">Member Directory</A>
</div>
</div>
```

app/test/right.erb

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
</div>
</div>
```

When i try to open google it opens it in complete window space.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your frameset should have the cols 26%,22.2%,51.8%, which simplifies your HTML to:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
<frameset rows="26%,22.2%,51.8%">
    <frame src="left" scrolling='no'>
    <frame src="/public/images/header.png" name="topy" scrolling='no'>
    <frame name="right" src="right" scrolling='no'>
</frameset>
```

Now, if it doesn't work, TRY using target="_parent.right" in the left.erb